# Akka-Typed Actor unit tests

Tags: scala, akka-typed

I've been trying to learn how to test akka-typed Actors. I've been referencing various examples online. I am successful at running the sample code but my efforts to write simple unit tests fail.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? My goal is to be able to write unit test that verify each behavior.

**build.sbt**

```
import Dependencies._

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.7"
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization := "com.example"
ThisBuild / organizationName := "example"

val akkaVersion = "2.6.18"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "akkat",
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      scalaTest % Test,
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed" % akkaVersion,
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-testkit-typed" % akkaVersion % Test,
      "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3"
    )
  )
```

**EmotionalFunctionalActor.scala**

```
package example

import akka.actor.typed.{ActorRef, Behavior}
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors

object EmotionalFunctionalActor {

  trait SimpleThing
  object EatChocolate extends SimpleThing
  object WashDishes extends SimpleThing
  object LearnAkka extends SimpleThing
  final case class Value(happiness: Int) extends SimpleThing
  final case class HowHappy(replyTo: ActorRef[SimpleThing]) extends SimpleThing

  def apply(happiness: Int = 0): Behavior[SimpleThing] = Behaviors.receive { (context, message) =>
    message match {
      case EatChocolate =>
        context.log.info(s"($happiness) eating chocolate")
        EmotionalFunctionalActor(happiness + 1)

      case WashDishes =>
        context.log.info(s"($happiness) washing dishes, womp womp")
        EmotionalFunctionalActor(happiness - 2)

      case LearnAkka =>
        context.log.info(s"($happiness) Learning Akka, yes!!")
        EmotionalFunctionalActor(happiness + 100)

      case HowHappy(replyTo) =>
        replyTo ! Value(happiness)
        Behaviors.same

      case _ =>
        context.log.warn("Received something i don't know")
        Behaviors.same
    }
  }
}
```

**EmoSpec.scala**

```
package example

import akka.actor.testkit.typed.scaladsl.ActorTestKit
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.AskPattern.Askable
import akka.util.Timeout
import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers

import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt

class EmoSpec extends AnyFlatSpec
  with BeforeAndAfterAll
  with Matchers {

  val testKit = ActorTestKit()

  override def afterAll(): Unit = testKit.shutdownTestKit()

  "Happiness Leve" should "Increase by 1" in {
    val emotionActor = testKit.spawn(EmotionalFunctionalActor())
    val probe = testKit.createTestProbe[EmotionalFunctionalActor.SimpleThing]()

    implicit val timeout: Timeout = 2.second
    implicit val sched = testKit.scheduler
    import EmotionalFunctionalActor._

    emotionActor ! EatChocolate
    probe.expectMessage(EatChocolate)

    emotionActor ? HowHappy
    probe.expectMessage(EmotionalFunctionalActor.Value(1))

    val current = probe.expectMessageType[EmotionalFunctionalActor.Value]
    current shouldBe 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear what problems you're encountering, so this answer is a bit of a shot in the dark with some observations.

You appear to be using the "command-then-query" pattern in testing this aspect of the behavior, which is OK (but see below for a different approach which I've found works really well).  There are two basic ways you can approach this and your test looks like a bit of a mixture of the two in a way that probably is not working.

Regardless of approach, when sending the initial `EatChocolate` message to the actor:

```scala
emotionActor ! EatChocolate
```

That message is sent to actor, not to the probe, so `probe.expectMessage` won't succeed.

There are two flavors of ask in Akka Typed.  There's a `Future`-based one for outside of an actor, where the asking machinery injects a special `ActorRef` to receive the reply and returns a `Future` which will be completed when the reply is received.  You can arrange for that `Future` to send its result to the probe:

```scala
val testKit = ActorTestKit()
implicit val ec = testKit.system.executionContext

// after sending EatChocolate
val replyFut: Future[EmotionalFunctionalActor.SimpleThing] = emotionActor ? HowHappy
replyFut.foreach { reply =>
  probe.ref ! reply
}
probe.expectMessage(EmotionalFunctionalActor.Value(1))
```

More succinctly, you can dispense with `Askable`, `Future`s, and an `ExecutionContext` and use `probe.ref` as the `replyTo` field in your `HowHappy` message:

```scala
emotionActor ! HowHappy(probe.ref`)
probe.expectMessage(EmotionalFunctionalActor.Value(1))
```

This is more succinct and will probably be less flaky (being less prone to timing issues) than the `Future`-based approach.  Conversely, since the `HowHappy` message appears designed for use with the ask pattern, the `Future`-based approach may better fulfill a "test as documentation" purpose for describing how to interact with the actor.

If using the `Future`-based approach with ScalaTest, it might be useful to have your suite extend `akka.actor.testkit.typed.scaladsl.ScalaTestWithActorTestKit`: this will provide some of the boilerplate and also mix in ScalaTest's `ScalaFutures` trait, which would let you write something like

```scala
val replyFut: Future[EmotionalFunctionalActor.SimpleThing] = emotionActor ? HowHappy
assert(replyFut.futureValue == EmotionalFunctionalActor.Value(1))
```

I tend to prefer the `BehaviorTestKit`, especially for cases where I'm not testing how two actors interact (this can still be done, it's just a bit laborious with the `BehaviorTestKit`).  This has the advantage of not having any timing at all and generally has less overhead for running tests.

```scala
val testKit = BehaviorTestKit(EmotionalFunctionalActor())
val testInbox = TestInbox[EmotionalFunctionalActor.SimpleThing]()

testKit.run(HowHappy(testInbox.ref))
testInbox.expectMessage(EmotionalFunctionalActor.Value(1))
```

As a side note, when designing a request-response protocol, it's generally a good idea to restrict the response type to the responses that might actually be sent, e.g.:

```scala
final case class HowHappy(replyTo: ActorRef[Value]) extends SimpleThing
```

This ensures that the actor can't reply with anything but a `Value` message and means that the asker doesn't have to handle any other type of message.  If there's a couple of different message types it could respond with, it might be worth having a `trait` which is only extended (or mixed in) by those responses:

```scala
trait HappinessReply
final case class Value(happiness: Int) extends HappinessReply
final case class HowHappy(replyTo: ActorRef[HappinessReply]) extends SimpleThing
```

Further, the reply often won't make sense as a message received by the sending actor (as indicated in this case by it being handled by the "Received something I don't know" case).  In this situation, `Value` shouldn't extend `SimpleThing`: it might even just be a bare `case class` and not extend anything.